# Count or Return Leading 0's in PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex, leading-zero

If I have

$num = '00000567';

I want to use PHP's preg match or split to split off the 0's so I can count them or count the 0's and have the regex return the variable. Can anyone help me out as the net have very few hits about leading 0's and mostly they're about removing them

Comment: all 0's in the number, or just leading 0's? e.g. `001` (2 zeroes leading) v.s. `010` (1 zero leading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace all non-zero to empty string:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/[^0]+/', '', $num);
//=> 00000
```

OR use `preg_match` to match zeroes only:

```
if (preg_match('/^0+/', $num, $m))
   echo $m[0];
```

Comment: Works wonders! /^ Matches the begining 0's and the + gets the rest following without getting the numbers. It was difficult to remember the exact output functions of the preg functions while regex has its own built it too. Which it would be nice to know if someone wants to. This is a good reminder for me to freshen up on some regex! Ty Ty

Comment: I wanted to comment about the speeds of the different answers and why this is still better for me...  (Microtime/60) Multi Line ltrim Approach x1000 times : 27640379.554272; Single Line preg_match Approach x1000 times : 27640379.554288; Single run - 27640379.554238 vs 27640379.554266 The verbosity vs gains are insignificant to me.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `regex` you can use `ltrim()`. Example:

```
$num = '00000567';
$new_num = ltrim($num, '0'); // $new_num = 567
$zeros = strlen($num) - strlen($new_num);
echo $zeros; //5
```

Comment: This is a better answer. Avoid using regex if you don't have to.

Comment: @Zortext - Im not going to downvote this for the easy reason it isn't what I asked and I am not going to up vote your comment for lacking reasons. I will give you some tests though. (Microtime/60) Multi Line ltrim Approach x1000 times : 27640379.554272; Single Line  preg_match Approach x1000 times : 27640379.554288;  My vote is that it is unnecessarily verbose for insignificant gains. There were slightly better gains in a single run though. 27640379.554238 vs 27640379.554266 but my vote stands. For clarity I used the answers' exact script.